# Broadcast Exception Timestamp Expired

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm developing a website using Laravel and Pusher on a Windows operating system. When I execute an event. I got the following error code:

> Illuminate \ Broadcasting \ BroadcastException

Timestamp expired:

Given timestamp **(2019-01-24T21:00:50Z)** not within 600s of server time **(2019-01-24T06:01:54Z)**

Comment: your time and your host time is not matching  correct the time for both

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer helped me overcome an error in my program.

Comment: This might help you in Pusher event debug... https://twitter.com/FirecampHQ/status/1101028779311460353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time and your host time is not matching correct the time for both,

Set your Machine Time that will match your Broadcast Timestamp. you will good to go.
Happy Coding.